# How do i fix "cant resolve" error in CSS for a Angular project?

Tags: css, angular

I was doing a mini project myself and decided to place a background image for another image ahd here is my CSS code:

```css
.child2 img {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-image: url('./assets/images/imageborder.png'); 
}
```

When I tried to run my Angular webpage,this popped up:

> Cant resolve ./assets/images/imageborder.png in /Users/[my name]/sites/Project A/src/app/home

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
url('/assets/images/imageborder.png')
```

or

```
url('~src/assets/images/imageborder.png')
```

Comment: Thank you kind person, i was able to solve it with your help